# Adding observations in Stata

Tags: database, stata

The basis of my database is violent events. I know in which grid-cell and on which date these events happened. For my analysis I use frequency of violent events in a certain grid-cell, country and year as the dependent variable. To create this frequency variable I `collapse` my violent event database and count the number of violent events in a certain grid-cell, in a certain year.

I want to include a value of 0 if there was no violent event in a certain grid-cell in a certain year. However, as my basis is the violent events database, I do not have these observations when I `collapse` my data. Is there any way to create a 0 value for observations in years and grid-cells where there was no violent event?

Before I `collapse` my dateset it looked like this

```
+--------------------------+
|Country Year Grid_cell_id |
|--------------------------|
|Benin    2012    365      |
|Benin    2012    365      |
|Benin    2012    367      |
|Benin    2014    365      |
|Benin    2014    365      |
|Benin    2014    365      | 
|Benin    2015    240      |
|Benin    2015    240      |
|Kenya    2012    430      |
|Kenya    2012    430      |
|Kenya    2013    467      |
|Kenya    2014    567      |
|Kenya    2014    567      |
|Kenya    2014    567      | 
+--------------------------+
```

Once I `collapse` my dataset, it looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
|Country  Year Grid_cell_id freq  |
|---------------------------------|
|Benin    2012    365        2    |
|Benin    2012    367        1    |
|Benin    2014    365        3    |
|Benin    2015    240        2    |
|Kenya    2012    430        2    |
|Kenya    2013    467        1    |
|Kenya    2014    567        3    |
+---------------------------------+
```

When I use `fillin` to create the 0 frequency value, I only use I only use  grid-cell_id and year, but I also want information on the country in which the grid-cell is located. I can easily come to the dataset below with the `fillin` function, but how can I preserve the country value, without using it as a `fillin` criterion.

```
+---------------------------------+
|Country  Year Grid_cell_id freq  |
|---------------------------------|
|Benin    2012    365        2    |
|.        2013    365        0    |
|.        2014    365        3    |
|.        2015    365        0    |
|Benin    2012    367        1    |
|.        2012    367        0    |
|.        2013    367        0    |
|.        2014    367        0    |
|.        2015    367        0    |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I create the problem mentioned and then solve it with `fillin`. See `help fillin` and also [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0011).

In this particular case, the problem could have been avoided altogether by using the `zero` option of `contract`. Indeed, to get a dataset of frequencies `contract` is often superior to `collapse`.

```
 sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. contract foreign rep78

. list, sepby(foreign)

     +--------------------------+
     | rep78    foreign   _freq |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |     1   Domestic       2 |
  2. |     2   Domestic       8 |
  3. |     3   Domestic      27 |
  4. |     4   Domestic       9 |
  5. |     5   Domestic       2 |
  6. |     .   Domestic       4 |
     |--------------------------|
  7. |     3    Foreign       3 |
  8. |     4    Foreign       9 |
  9. |     5    Foreign       9 |
 10. |     .    Foreign       1 |
     +--------------------------+

. fillin foreign rep78

. list, sepby(foreign)

     +------------------------------------+
     | rep78    foreign   _freq   _fillin |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |     1   Domestic       2         0 |
  2. |     2   Domestic       8         0 |
  3. |     3   Domestic      27         0 |
  4. |     4   Domestic       9         0 |
  5. |     5   Domestic       2         0 |
  6. |     .   Domestic       4         0 |
     |------------------------------------|
  7. |     1    Foreign       .         1 |
  8. |     2    Foreign       .         1 |
  9. |     3    Foreign       3         0 |
 10. |     4    Foreign       9         0 |
 11. |     5    Foreign       9         0 |
 12. |     .    Foreign       1         0 |
     +------------------------------------+

. replace _freq = 0 if _fillin
(2 real changes made)

. drop _fillin

. list, sepby(foreign)

     +--------------------------+
     | rep78    foreign   _freq |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |     1   Domestic       2 |
  2. |     2   Domestic       8 |
  3. |     3   Domestic      27 |
  4. |     4   Domestic       9 |
  5. |     5   Domestic       2 |
  6. |     .   Domestic       4 |
     |--------------------------|
  7. |     1    Foreign       0 |
  8. |     2    Foreign       0 |
  9. |     3    Foreign       3 |
 10. |     4    Foreign       9 |
 11. |     5    Foreign       9 |
 12. |     .    Foreign       1 |
     +--------------------------+
```

EDIT

You seem to be ignoring the advice to use `contract, zero` which automatically adds observations with frequency zero.

Otherwise please note the detailed advice in the Stata tag wiki on presenting data examples and consider this variation on combining identifier and year using `egen`. For any long-term dataset, it seems unwise to assume that grid cells remain in the same country, so that is not assumed.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str35 Country int(Year Grid_cell_id) byte freq
"Benin" 2012 365 2
"Benin" 2012 367 1
"Benin" 2014 365 3
"Benin" 2015 240 2
"Kenya" 2012 430 2
"Kenya" 2013 467 1
"Kenya" 2014 567 3
end

egen Id = concat(Grid_cell_id Country), p(" ")
fillin Id Year 
replace Grid_cell_id = real(word(Id, 1))
replace Country = trim(subinstr(Id, word(Id, 1), "", 1))
drop Id
replace freq = 0 if _fillin
drop _fillin
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so soon! I still have a question: when using the fillin code, all variables I don't use to select the fillin criteria on get a . value. I only need the grid-cell and year for the fillin criterium, but I also want information on the country in which the grid-cell is located. Is there anyway I can easily add the correct country for all added fillin observations?

Comment: Your question was broad and lacked a data example, but the essence seemed clear enough. Now that you are adding a complication, the absence of a data example is more serious. Please see the Stata tag wiki for detailed advice on giving examples. FWIW, _criterion_ is the singular of _criteria_.

Comment: I've edited my queston to  give a better idea of my problen, again many thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `egen group = group(Country Grid_cell_id)` and then `fillin group year`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that solves my problem as I loose both country and grid_cell_id for all added observations after using `fillin`. I later want to use country x year fixed effects and grid_cell_id fixed effects.

Comment: Noted. Please see revised answer.